# Qt - Adding dynamic controls to a placeholder

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dynamic, qt4

**I am looking for the best way to dynamically swap in and out controls within Qt on a predefined layout created from the Qt Designer.**

I come from a ASP.NET background, where often I would use the idea of a "placeholder" for this type of task and add controls as children at runtime.

Does Qt support this type of functionality or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a layout control to any widget and later on dynamically add controls to the layout:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    QLabel *plbl = new QLabel(myform);
    plbl->setText(QLabel::tr(L"My dynamic text box"));
    mylayout->addWidget(plbl);
}
```

Edit: There are different Layout classes that support different "fill" styles (e.g. horizontal next to each other, grid layout, vertical layout, etc.). You won't need any placeholders or similar - just a widget (or layout) as parent to fill.

Answer (score 0):

If your Qt Layout already uses layouts, then best idea would be to leave some place for runtime controls in layout tree, or perhaps even a empty layout just for those. Layouts have ability to dynamicaly add or remove widgets and sub-layouts, so that solves the problem. If you want to insert new widgets immediatley after removing old ones interface might flicker as qt will try to reuse temporarly freed space. It might slow application down if there are any slow rendering widgets.

Another soultion would be to insert empty widget - that is more similar to ASP.NET approach. It is a bit more crude method, but might be a good way to avoid flickering of interface. It would prevent layout from reusing space even if you don't display any widget and leave unused space - it might suggest to a user, that after some interaction something might appear here - if it's desired behavior i would suggest this way.

If you have several sets of controls apperaing always in the same groups you might consider using QStackedWidget, that allows you to create those widgets already at design stage and swich between groups at runtime.